# Unable to delete a Node in jackrabbit

Tags: java, jcr, jackrabbit

I am trying to delete a Node which I have saved using jackrabbit but I get this error.

```
Failed to  delete file
! javax.jcr.nodetype.ConstraintViolationException: Unable to perform operation. Node is protected.
```

Here is the code I have used to save it:

```
            session = repository.login(new SimpleCredentials("admin", "admin".toCharArray()));

            Node parent = (Node) itemAtPath(parentPath, session);
            Node newNode = parent.addNode(nodeName);
            newNode.addMixin("mix:versionable");
            session.save(); // Create Root Node

            VersionableChanges changes = new VersionableChanges(newNode.getSession());
            changes.checkout(newNode);

            Binary binary = session.getValueFactory().createBinary(in);
            newNode.setProperty(PROPERTY_DATA, binary);
            newNode.setProperty(PROPERTY_NAME, fileName + System.currentTimeMillis());
            newNode.setProperty(PROPERTY_CREATEDBY, createdBy);
            newNode.setProperty(PROPERTY_CREATEDDATE, createdDate);
            newNode.setProperty(PROPERTY_COMMENT, comment);
            Value value = session.getValueFactory().createValue(binary);
            changes.checkin();
            session.save();
```

Here is the code I am using to delete it:

```
            session = repository.login(new SimpleCredentials("admin", "admin".toCharArray()));
            Version fileVersion = null;
            Node fileNode = null;

            if (version != null && !version.isEmpty()) {
                fileVersion = session.getWorkspace().getVersionManager().getVersionHistory(path).getVersion(version);
            } else {
                fileVersion = session.getWorkspace().getVersionManager().getBaseVersion(path);
            }

            fileNode = fileVersion.getFrozenNode();
            fileNode.remove();
            //need to save session to persist the remove operation
            session.save();
```

How can I overcome this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frozen nodes are protected because deleting them would (maybe) put the version store in a corrupted state. In order to remove a "complete" version from the history, you have to something like this:

```
VersionHistory history = session.getWorkspace().getVersionManager()
                            .getVersionHistory(info.getVersionedNodePath());
history.removeVersion(info.getVersionName());
session.save();
```

Comment: The code is deleting the complete version. The version node, the frozen node and what else is part of the version. I thought that was what you tried to do.

Comment: I tried `history.removeVersion(fileVersion.getName());` but now I get this error `Failed to  delete file
! javax.jcr.ReferentialIntegrityException: Unable to remove version. At least once referenced.`

Comment: Ok. I guess that's because the version you are trying to delete is the current version. You might need to remove the original node itself before you can remove the attached version node.

Comment: I tried Node `deleteNode =  session.getNode(path);     deleteNode.remove();      history.removeVersion(fileVersion.getName());` as you suggested i.e. removing the original node itself but still doesn't seem to work. The same error persists.

Comment: I got it to work. I removed `history.removeVersion()` from my `else` and added it to my `if` it worked. I think the issue was the file I was trying to delete node which didn't have any version.